# Are nick names the place for propaganda

Tags: discussion

As I got more information on the situation, I'm able now to formulate the question, originally was point **C** in [that](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8220/20315) question.

originally it was asked as follows:

- *what it all about for reinstating something - is an advertisement in nicknames of mods is a new future or again how good of an example it makes.*

### clarification

It was sure interesting to know about the commonitions which was in [2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340906/259155), however, the main point is - are nicknames allowed to be the means to clarify stances on subjects, isn't a bio for all that, if u like to do so.

or indeed it is okay and all welcome, there is quite a list of persons who I would like to be reinstated if the word "reinstate" is a magic one, and if it is not even required then I have even more to write in my nickname.

Sure there are fancy nicknames out there, but is it appropriate to use that freedom to agitate bystanders to participate in a 2y old dog fight. Never perishing loyalty is all good and great, legends and songs are written about it, but ...

I mean is it only for mods or regular users can participate too in what **they** deem important?

- I cautiously try to not bring examples, to avoid the spiral of death.
- as not a native english writer I may be less picky about the words I choose, because of my limited vocabulary and zero emotional attachment to the context of those words, so if it rubs against fur it may or may not be intentional, keep it in mind. All the good words come from spell checking plugin.

Comment: So, yours is a "request for clarification", while something which has swept a lasting emotional wave across all SE communities is a "dog fight"...

Comment: I actually thought that L.Dutch's whole pseudo was just some kind of... I don't know, a pseudo! I pronounced it in my head like it was Rheinstate (as in "mind"), not re-instate (as in prep' + in-side). How silly I can be sometimes x_x.

Comment: Asking about whether it's propaganda is a bit overkill. I mean, the opinion is affirmed, but a single statement on a name would be hardly considered one. Like if you wore a T-shirt with the words "Be vegan" on it, but saying nothing more about it unless asked to.

Comment: @Tortliena propaganda may be an exaggeration or local habit in my country to name such things in that way, so as it possible come with short slogans or even a few letters which may bring trouble by the law(in more than one country), so it may be not that much of exaggeration. "Be vegan" - that one is microaggression for sure, "I'm vegan" okay, it's your business, but there is a profile page where u can put things about u to know if someone is interested in that - idk, so so. initially, I thought it's Monica's account with strange stuff in the front, idk for 5 sec once I saw it.

Comment: @MolbOrg Well, now you know it's not an ideal word if you wish to stay neutral ^^. To prevent this kind of thing from happening, I like to use Linguee's website to double-check the main topic, because you have some context added to the translations. It has Russian (based on your SE activity, you seem pretty fluent in it), so it's nice and good, or can I say это хорошо instead ^^?

Comment: @Tortliena I'll keep the place in mind. I use grammarly plugin(usually, on desktop), it is a great help to me, it offers alternatives(sometimes). Found it also from someones comment here on wb, one recommended it to me. Sometimes a problem is not in describing things but boil them down to a single word and it does not matter how fluent one is, that a writer talent which I do not have. So as it is a result of cultural differences, it again does not depend on fluency. So I gues we just embrace them and go with it, and I quite proud to be a reminder of those existance, lol.

Comment: @Tortliena as your detective work, yes it is correct. На здоровье, lol. But yeah the word is less often used standalone, it needs some subject. [Это] хороший сайт, может пригодиться.

Comment: This question should really be migrated to meta.stackexchange because it is about a site-wide policy rather than something unique to Worldbuilding SE. The mods and users of Worldbuilding SE are not responsible for Stack Exchange-wide trends

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica The way the question is stated is also very, very leading

Comment: @user2352714 u can read the answer it's from Community Managers, and honestly current rules are good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's very little that we disallow in usernames - profanity, slurs, sexual content, hate towards others - are some examples but it's not an exhaustive list. We also don't take it kindly if you make an attempt to look like someone you're not - whether that person is famous or another user on the site. In particular, trying to make yourself appear to be a moderator by adding a diamond to your username is generally prevented by our filters.

Otherwise, we are OK with y'all putting whatever you want in your usernames. If we haven't acted at this point, after a year and a half, we're not going to do it now. Regarding the events of 2019 specifically, we understand that it's a point of pain for many and that forcing those who choose to commemorate or support someone in avatars or usernames is a personal one and forcing removal would only further that pain.

We respect our users' decisions for when (or if) they choose to change their usernames, even if it acts as a reminder of a time we hope never to repeat. And, in some small way, they may act as a reminder for us to work to prevent it from repeating, too.

---

For anyone who doesn't know me, I'm one of the Community Managers here at Stack Exchange. Hiya!

Comment: nice to know there is such freedom and care about the feelings of others from Se side. I always have a problem expressing myself, especially in short sentences for the reasons mentioned. I'm cool about monica case, not a fan, even if she was nice person, but sitting on multiple stools is hard, her absence on wb has pros and cons. Not advocating in forcing nickname changes, without heavy reasons. So I guess follow up would be how do I check if my potential change to a nick name is appropriate? or have I test it, and if I do not guess few times, refining it, can I get 1 year permaban. Trump?

Comment: It's unlikely you'd get banned for a year because of a username unless you intentionally started testing the mods by changing it to things that were intentionally possibly considered offensive and were warned and suspended several times prior to that. Mods have the ability to reset usernames at any time to the default and will often do that along with sending a mod message explaining the change and asking the person to avoid such things in the future. We tend to assume people do things without poor intentions unless they're also doing things that would be offensive on their own.

Comment: nice to know, so thorough testing, maybe I was just too alarmed by that [reminder](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8209/20315), as second warning already puts on a ban spiral. And as a somewhat autistic person not sure what others may find offensive, so an international user not sure about nuances of context in some cases. Sure I'm all cooperation, just it may require few interations before, u know a cool name pops out, it's a name after all, have to be good. But okay, understood. Nice to see u, come here more often, thanks ;)